# What is the difference between pause and debug in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

From the API it seems [pause](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/pause.html#) and [debug](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/debug.html#) are pretty similar. What exactly is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are utility commands from cypress package, can be performed in the same way (chained off of cy or off another command) and there is no timeout period. But the **difference** are:

- pause() will stop the test execution to inspect the web application, the DOM, the network, whereas debug() will stop only when the developer tools are open
- pause() does not provide any debug information, whereas debug() give the details in browser console tab
- Using pause() we can find 'next' button option in the test runner, which allow us to execute the code step by step, debug() doesn't have the feature.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is already explained in the docs.

**Pause**

```
This does not set a debugger in your code, unlike .debug()
```

**Debug**

```
You need to have your Developer Tools open for .debug() to hit the breakpoint.
```

Comment: So what does that mean in practical terms? When would you prefer to use a debug over a pause? "This does not set a debugger...", so what is a 'debugger'? To answer myself: looks like debug relates to browser commands, whereas pause is a similar command but then within cypress?!

Comment: Exactly. `debugger` is a keyword in JavaScript which triggers the corresponding DeveloperTools inside your browser, if they are opened. `pause()` seems to be for the Cypress tools and triggers regardless of whether the DeveloperTools are open or not.

Comment: In practical terms this means that `debugger` stops the execution of your JavaScript at that point. The browser is then responsible for resuming execution (cypress itself is paused at this point).

Comment: Ok. Is there any advantage using debugger then (within the context of Cypress testing) compared to pause?

Comment: `debugger` allows you to use your browsers debugging tools for the tests. E.g. looking into variables, manipulating the dom, etc. etc.

Comment: Yeah, so with `pause` you will analyse / debug within Cypress, and with `debug` you will analyse/ debug within your Browser devtools. Makes sense now.